# Miele condenser dryer T8013C not drying, takes too long to dry, why?

Tags: dryer

My Miele dryer is taking 5hrs to dry clothes. I have cleaned all the lint traps. What else should I do? I am fairly handy (e.g. small repairs, building computers), except I have never done a dryer before. Please advise.

Comment: Can you add some detail to the question? Is this a recent change, or has it always taken this long? Is it possible the issue is with the spin cycle on your washer, meaning the clothes are wetter than normal when they go into the dryer? It looks like the dryer has a "dryness" setting, have you changed that at all?

Comment: You mentioned you have cleaned the lint traps, but have you also removed and cleaned the condenser itself? It looks like the instruction indicate it could be due to having clothes with lots of metal (zippers, etc). which could interfere with the moisture sensors. You can try running a timed program for a shorter period and see if your clothes are actually dry after maybe 2 hours, and the sensor is just making the dryer run longer than needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have fixed my problem. Here is what I did as reference for others.

After cleaning out all the lint in all the "air" filters, I found the condenser was completely clogged with lint.

[image: Miele condenser image]

The condenser is a long box. In the manual and online posts, the instruction is to rinse it with a shower head. However, there is so much lint stuck in the honey-comb-like structure, water from a shower head just could not flush everything out.

Ultimately after various attempts, I filled the bathtub with water to submerge the condenser, and moved the condenser vigorously back and forth to create strong "waves" in the bathtub water. The water pushed all the lint out.

Be sure to collect the lint before you drain the tub, so your tub doesn't get clogged.

Once the condenser was cleaned, the dryer was normal again.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it solved, and thanks for coming back to post your answer. Be sure to click the check-mark so others will know it's been resolved, too. (I think the system makes you wait 24 hours before you can do that, though.)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even know we were supposed to service this. Also, next level clean option here: https://youtu.be/AUEX5B5Xi4s?si=3gb7Oo4Rr7rLX5Ju _however_ watch to the very end and I might try just removing the very bottom panel

Answer (score 1):

Woah, there is no filter in front on the intake fan. Try this:

Remove the two screws, slide the grille to the *left* then out

The fan isn't sharp, if you have small enough hands simply reach in. Use a small brush if you have one

[image: rubbish]

[image: gap]

[image: fan]